# How to pass a match from the regex in a condition to the rule in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, regular-expression

I have an .htaccess file with rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /apples/*
RewriteRule . /page/faqs.php?cat=apples&question=%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /bananas/*
RewriteRule . /page/faqs.php?cat=bananas&question=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I want it to work like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(apples|bananas)/*
RewriteRule . /page/faqs.php?cat=$1&question=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

with the $1 being the matched value (apples or bananas). How can I pass something like this from a condition to a rule?

Comment: Why are not testing apples|bananas in URI at the RewriteRule stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(apples|bananas)/*
> RewriteRule . /page/faqs.php?cat=$1&question=%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

Almost. But you need to use `%1` instead of `$1` as a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` *pattern*). `$1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (but you have none, so `$1` would always be empty in this example).

However, as @PatrickMevzek suggested in comments, you should be performing this check on the URL in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead (more efficient and one less directive). In this case you would use `$1` like you are doing. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(apples|bananas)/ /page/faqs.php?cat=$1&question=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You didn't have an *anchor* in your original *CondPattern* (`/(apples|bananas)/*`) so this would have matched anywhere inside the URL. I've assumed this should be at the start of the URL-path? Also the trailing `*` is not doing what you think it is. The `*` in regex speak repeats the previous character 0 or more times (it's not a "wildcard" character). So, this would have only served to match multiple slashes (which I doubt was the intention)!

I've also added the `L` (`last`) flag. I assume you don't want any other rewrites to occur after this one? This doesn't really matter if this is the only mod_rewrite directive in the file, but if you added later directives then the `L` may be required.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've made my life much easier today!